# Retrieving a post's Title in Wordpress without echo'ing

Tags: wordpress, post, title

I'm currently looking for a way to find the Title of the current post/page you're on, without it auto echoing the way that the_title(); does. Also, I don't think get_the_title() is suitable as you'll need to give that an ID (of the post/page) and I don't think I can retrieve that without first using the 'loop'?

Any advice would be much appreciated chaps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always have access to the current post/page's ID. Normally it's $post->ID globally. `get_the_title()` is definitely the solution you're looking for.